# AWS Storage Types

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to understand the fundamental differences between several different types of storage available on AWS, specifically:

- SSD
- Magnetic
- "Provisioned IOPS"
- Snapshot storage

I am stunned to find no clear definition of each of these in the AWS docs, so I ask: How are these storage types different, and what use cases/scenarios are appropriate for each?

Comment: This page appears to provide very clear definitions of the different EBS volume types: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're referring to Elastic Block Store (EBS). EBS provides persistent block level storage volumes for Amazon EC2 instances. EBS volumes come in 3 types:

1. Provisioned IOPS (SSD)
2. General Purpose (SSD)
3. Magnetic

Each type has different performance characteristics and costs. See [EBS volume types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html) for more details. The list above is ordered from high to low, by both [price](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/) and by potential [IOPS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-io-characteristics.html).

EBS snapshots are something else entirely. All EBS volumes, regardless of volume type, can be snapshotted and durably stored.

Answer (score 2):

Instance storage options:

Magnetic - Slowest/cheapest magnetic disk backed storage

SSD - Faster/more expensive solid state backed storage

"Provisioned IOPS" - FastEST/most expensive but guaranteed (at the physical level) speed of input/output operations per second.

from Google:

> IOPS (Input/Output Operations Per Second, pronounced eye-ops) is a common performance measurement used to benchmark computer storage devices like hard disk drives (HDD), solid state drives (SSD), and storage area networks (SAN).

This [link](http://blog.flux7.com/mysql-benchmark-a-matchup-of-aws-ssd-drives) has more fine grained details on SSD/Magnetic disk comparisons, granted it seems geared towards databases.

---

Snapshots are backups and are entirely separate from AWS 'hard drive' offerings.